# strophe.js chat state notifications

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe.js

I am trying to implement strophe.js chat state plugin but unable to find any readme document.

Saw the similar question but there was no answer.
[StropheJs Chat State Notification plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32264622/strophejs-chat-state-notification-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Strophe plugin for chat states [here](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugin-chatstates). All plugins follow the XMPP extension protocols (XEPs). So you can get the use cases from their respective XEP which they implement. In this case the plugin implements the [XEP-0085](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html). For a detailed implementation you can see converse.js core plugin [here](https://github.com/conversejs/converse.js/blob/master/src/headless/converse-core.js). Note that the XEP for chat states only provides a protocol to share activity information (typing status, etc) taking place between users, however it does not specify anything about the state of a message. So if you need a feature like 'message seen', you may want to consider Chat Markers ([XEP-0333](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0333.html)) instead.

Comment: FYI, the link to the converse.js core plugin is broken, because they removed `converse-core.js` from their code base from `v4.0.4`.